# Write objective function and constraints in LP format

Tags: cplex, cvxpy

I am using CVXPY to solve an objective function. The variables are big matrices. I want to create a function to write the objective function and constraints to a text file which can then be used for other solvers such as CPLEX. One way to do it is to explicitly write every variable as string and concatenate them to create objective function. However, I am looking for alternate ways so that the expression does not become too big. For example, if the variables are as follows:

```
[ w11, w12

  w21,  w22 ]
```

then the expression will be w11+w12+w21+w22. As we can imagine, if the variable matrix grows, the expression will grow as well.

Is there a way to initialize variables as matrices in LP format?

Comment: Are you aware that CPLEX is available as one of the [options](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/advanced/index.html#solve-method-options) for the `solve` method in CVXPY? You can export the LP file from CPLEX using the [cplex_filename](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/advanced/index.html#setting-solver-options) option.

Comment: I see. Thanks! I don't have CPLEX installed yet, but I see the option now to export the LP file.

Answer (score -1):

the matlab code to write a text file for using in a cplex solver ...may be it is of help and you can post it if you have something better

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;
%fileID = fopen('test2_in.txt','wt');

filename = fullfile('"E:\...','ex_1.txt'); 

 fileID = fopen('ex_1.txt','w+'); 


formatSpec = 'MAXIMIZE \n Obj:';
fprintf(fileID,formatSpec);


obj_coeff = [0.12 0.15];
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Writing Objective function for the problem
for ii = 1:length(obj_coeff) 
     if ii==length(obj_coeff)
        formatSpec = '(%d) X_%d';
    else
        formatSpec = ' (%d) X_%d +';
    end
    fprintf(fileID,formatSpec,obj_coeff(ii),ii);
end
formatSpec = '\n\nSUBJECT TO \n';
fprintf(fileID,formatSpec);
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
%writing constraints
temp = 1;
for jj = 1:length(obj_coeff) 
    if jj==length(obj_coeff)
        formatSpec = ' X_%d <= %d\n r %d:';
        fprintf(fileID,formatSpec ,jj,temp+1);
        temp = temp+1;
    else
        formatSpec = ' X_%d +';
        fprintf(fileID,formatSpec,jj);
    end        
end
formatSpec = '\n\n binary\n ';
fprintf(fileID,formatSpec);
for ii = 1:1:length(obj_coeff) 
    formatSpec = 'X_%d ';
    fprintf(fileID,formatSpec,ii); 
end

formatSpec = '\n\nEND';
fprintf(fileID,formatSpec);
fclose(fileID);
```